# JavaSE: First thread to call a method interrupts all other threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 2 threads running at the same time.. racing if you will through a series of loops and such.  The first thread to reach the end of its computing I have calling a method.  I would like to know if that method can interrupt all other threads.. or lock them out so only the first thread to call that method will run that method.

*EDIT*
figured I'd throw in an example:

A class that creates threads:

```
class Runner extends Thread{

    public void run(){
        //for loops
            //math, math, math
        // while
            // random numbers, math
        // yada yada

        methodCall();
    }
}
```

methodCall() within the main method

```
public static *synchronized perhaps* void methodCall(){
    //first call wins
    //interrupt all other threads created
}
```

Comment: Maybe a thread group contained these threads is ok.hope that helped,for more detail, please refer http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074481/java-concurrency/java-101--understanding-java-threads--part-4---thread-groups--volatility--and-threa.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this.  Make the method `synchronized`, so that it can only be run by one thread at a time, and within the method set a flag which will cause future runs of the method to abort.

Note:  if the method is an instance method rather than a static method, and the different threads use different instances of the class the method is in, you will need to synchronize on a global lock, such as a static `Object` in the class.

Comment: Excellent.. that takes care of the lock out.. I figured that would be easy.. but what about interrupting the other threads so they stop computing and gracefully end?

Comment: If you want to stop the other threads, that takes more code.  You have to have code executed by all threads that checks a flag, probably a volatile boolean, periodically, to see if the first thread has completed, and if it has, gracefully terminate processing for the thread checking the flag.  The synchronized method then sets the flag to indicate the first thread has completed.  If it's likely that the other threads are waiting for locks, you can call interrupt() on them to have them abandon their waits.

Comment: You can also call Thread.stop() on all the other threads, but that is deprecated and highly nonrecommended.

Comment: I read up more about shared variables.. Oracles Guarded Blocks tutorial actually made some sense.  I'm gonna test that out with a shared flag set to false.. have my thread objects run their loop while that flag is false and the first one to that method will flip that flag to true.. just hope the program responds fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try ending your competitor threads with a call to a `synchronized` method which sets the value of some null-initialized variable. The winner will call the method and get a lock, find the value to be `null`, and set its name there. The loser will get the next lock bit find the winner's name already set.

```java
public class RaceJudge
{
    private static Runner m_tskWinner = null ;

    /**
     * The "methodCall()" from the question.
     * @param tskCompetitor the Runner that is trying to cross the
     *   line.
     * @return true if that task won the race.
     */
    public static synchronized boolean crossFinishLine( Runner tskCompetitor )
    {
        if( m_tskWinner == null )
        {
            m_tskWinner = tskCompetitor ;
            return true ;
        }
        else
            return false ;
    }
}
```

Thus…

```
public class Runner extends Thread
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // the aforementioned yadda yadda
        RaceJudge.crossFinishLine(this) ;
    }
}
```